# What to do with this kind of data?

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, data-preprocessing

I have two questions:

1. In a population of 10000 people, there are 40% men and 60% women.
   I record how many men and women use a kind of service. 
   The result is 600 men and 700 women are using this service. 
   How do I know 600:700 is different from the proportion of the population(4:6)? Can I use chi-square test?

2.
For example, in an experiment, I choose a population of bird(each has a specific ID) and put an item in their territory at different time and place for 30 times. I record which kind of bird(has a mate or not)will interact with the item.

so sometimes a specific individual will interact with this item more than once. 
Should I just see this individual each time as a different data because its status might change?

Comment: Try to understand the definition of population, sample, parameter, estimate, etc. first.